# Remove colon in the caption of a figure without using caption package

Tags: captions, punctuation

I know that I can [Remove colon in the caption of a figure if the caption is empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/remove-colon-in-the-caption-of-a-figure-if-the-caption-is-empty) when I simply use the `caption` package. But let's say I am using a journal-specific class (e.g. `elsarticle`) that has it's own definition of caption layout. So adding the `caption` package gives me an *unsupported document class (or package)* warning.

So the question it - can I remove the colon from the caption of a figure if the caption is empty WITHOUT using the `caption` package?

Comment: I also use the elsarticle class, slightly redefined, because it's pretty and works well, not necessarily to submit to Elsevier journals.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A preliminary remark: If a journal you're submitting an article to requires you to use the `elsarticle` document class, it may be a *poor idea* to modify the caption style defined by the class. Your journal's style guidelines probably also state something to the effect that every float should have a (nonempty) caption, in which case some kind of separator (such as a colon) between the float's number and caption is generally needed.

Here's the definition of the `\@makecaption` command contained in the file `elsarticle.cls`

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip\footnotesize
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
```

The two arguments of the `\@makecaption` macro are `[Float] <num>` and the caption's text, respectively. [Float] can be "Figure", "Table", or the name of any other floating environment recognized by LaTeX.

There are two ways to suppress the insertion of a colon following the float's name and number.

**Method 1** : *Remove the colon globally* because the mandatory arguments (the stuff inside curly braces) of *all* `\caption` commands will always be empty. To achieve this, you could load the `etoolbox` package and issue the following commands:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1: #2}{#1}{}{}
\makeatother
```

**Method 2**: Remove the colon *whenever (and only if) the mandatory argument of the `\caption` command is empty*. In this case, you may want to employ the following redefinition of the `\@makecaption` command:

```
\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%       
\vskip\abovecaptionskip\footnotesize
\sbox\@tempboxa{#2}         % place contents of #2 into a scratch TeX box
\ifdim \wd\@tempboxa = 0pt  % test if scratch box has zero width
   \centering #1 \par       % if yes, typeset only #1 (the float's name and number)
\else                       % if no, proceed with default definition
   \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
   \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
     #1: #2\par
   \else
     \global \@minipagefalse
     \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
   \fi
\fi
\vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
```

Comment: This will remove the colon also when the caption is not empty, which is not what the OP is asking for. However, I agree that if the style has always a colon and this is a submission, then *every* figure should have a non empty caption.

Comment: OK, I had interpreted the OP's question as wanting to remove the colon in all instances. Let me rework the answer to that the colon removal occurs only if the argument of the `\caption` command is truly empty.

Comment: @Mico It's my first LaTeX submission so thank you for highlighting the issue with modifying journal's default style commands. However, the journal requires me to give figure captions as a list separately from the figures. So I am not sure how to deal with that, without modifying `\@makecaption` as you, @egreg and @Holle suggested...

Comment: @GeekOnAcid:  To provide a list of figures (on a separate page, right?), just type `\clearpage\listoffigures\clearpage`. This generates the equivalent of a table of contents, but containing only the figures. Likewise, the command `\listoftables` generates a list of all tables.

Comment: @Mico Yes, I know that, but the point is that if I generate the `\listoffigures` without giving any name in curly brackets for `\caption` (i.e. `\caption[text]{}`) it will create the list but also create a colon for the figure label - which is what I am trying to avoid:)

Comment: @GeekOnAcid: In this case, either the global method above or the method that applies if the argument of the caption command is empty will work for you.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, let me remark that if you're preparing a paper for a submission to a journal, such a change will be probably removed (and will annoy the people in charge of production). If the publisher's style wants a colon there, it means that *no* caption should be empty.

Anyway, here's a patch for `elsarticle`:

```
\documentclass{elsarticle}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1: #2}
  {#1\sbox8{#2}\ifdim\wd8=\z@\else: #2\fi}
  {}{\ddt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Here}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}
\caption{}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The original definition is

```
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip\footnotesize
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
```

so I patch the command with a check that the argument `#2` (the caption text) is empty. However the usual `\if\relax\detokenize{#2}\relax` fails, because the caption text always begins with `\ignorespaces`. Thus it's better to check if the caption text typesets something.

Comment: Is the second patch command necessary? The `\else` part of the `\ifdim` clause will only be entered if the width of the box containing `#1: #2` exceeds `\hsize`. This, in turn, will only ever happen (unless `\hsize` is truly minuscule!) if #2 is nonempty, won't it?

Comment: @Mico You're right.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the class elsarticle than you can (re)format the figure caption with the following lines:

```
\makeatletter

\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip\footnotesize
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip} 

\makeatother
```