# Interaction of hyperref, capt-of and redefinition of @makecaption

Tags: captions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove colon in the caption of a figure without using caption package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41597/remove-colon-in-the-caption-of-a-figure-without-using-caption-package)

This is a very tough question and I have posted minimum example below.

1. Because I don't want my figures to float I use **center** environment and **capt-of** package.
2. I have tweaked **@makecaption** in a way that there is only figure name (no colon) displayed when figure name is empty.
3. I also use **hyperref** package.

When working **all three together**, I get bunch of "**Extra \else.**" errors.  Can you find the problem?  Maybe I have redefined **@makecaption** badly?

Regards.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
% tweaked article.cls @makecaption: no caption text no ":" 
\newcommand*{\captionlabeldelim}{}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \ifx #2\ignorespaces 
   \renewcommand*{\captionlabeldelim}{}
  \else
   \renewcommand*{\captionlabeldelim}{:\ }
  \fi
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1\captionlabeldelim #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1\captionlabeldelim #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[clip]{bla.eps}
\captionof{figure}{x}
\end{center}%

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[clip]{bla.eps}
\captionof{figure}{}
\end{center}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the package `caption`? It's much easier instead of redefining something.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel I hate using the whole package with dozen of commands for only one small purpose...

Comment: @Pygmalion The reason people use packages is that the LaTeX kernel is very inflexible. Well-constructed packages address this and the interactions which can occur with other packages. Thus 'simple' changes are often anything but at the code level.

Comment: @JosephWright OK, got the message.  Yet, Mico's little solution is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As addressed in an answer to a [similar, but not entirely identical question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/41597/5001), you can achieve your objective of removing the colon if the argument of `\caption` (or `\caption-of`) is empty by re-defining `\@makecaption`. The following modified form of your MWE shows how this may be done.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % [demo] needed just for this MWE
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{% % #2 is argument of \caption and \captionof command     
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#2}        % place #2 into a scratch TeX box
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa = 0pt % test if scratch box has zero width
    \centering #1 \par       % if yes, typeset only #1 (the float's name and number)
  \else                      % else, proceed with default definition
    \sbox\@tempboxa{#1: #2}%
    \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
      #1: #2\par
    \else
      \global \@minipagefalse
      \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
    \fi
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[clip]{bla.eps}
\captionof{figure}{xyz} \label{fig:bla1}
\end{center}%

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[clip]{bla.eps}
\captionof{figure}{} \label{fig:bla2}
\end{center}%

And here are cross-references to \autoref{fig:bla1} and \autoref{fig:bla2}.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OK, this works.  Thanks!  Is there a *simple* explanation why my redefinition did not work?

Comment: @Pygmalion -- the main problem with your MWE is that `\ifx` tests for equality of *both* character and category codes of the items being compared. However, `\ignorespaces` (which is, after all, a macro) cannot be equal, in this very specific sense, to `#2` unless the argument of the `\caption` or `\captionof` command happens to be the macro `\ignorespaces` -- not likely to be the case, right? In contrast, my MWE tests whether a "box" containing `#2` has zero width -- which will be true if the argument of `\captionof` is empty.