# How can I have figure labels without captions in tufte-book?

Tags: captions, tufte

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/remove-colon-in-the-caption-of-a-figure-if-the-caption-is-empty) question shows how to remove the needless : from a figure with no caption, while leaving the "Figure X" label intact. The solution is to include the 
caption package.

Unfortunately, the tufte-book class doesn't seem to like this solution, as shown in the MWE below, which produces the warning:

```
Package caption Warning: \caption will not be redefined since it's already
(caption)                redefined by a document class or package which is
(caption)                unknown to the caption package.
See the caption package documentation for explanation.
```

[This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/41597/remove-colon-in-the-caption-of-a-figure-without-using-caption-package) question shows a circumvention that avoids using the caption package, but modifying the MWE to use it instead yields exactly the same output as before.

I don't actually need any captions at all in this document, just figure labels, so anything that gets rid of the darn : and centers the "Figure X" bit would be ideal. Suggestions?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
%\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makecaption}{#1: #2}{#1}{}{}
\makeatother



\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{graphic.pdf}
    \caption[Caption for the list of figures]{}
    \label{fig:figureX}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{graphic.pdf}
    \caption[Caption for the list of figures]{With caption}
    \label{fig:figureX}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

Output:
 [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are patching the wrong command.  In the `tufte-book` class, it is `\@caption` and the relevant part is originally:

```
\@tufte@caption@font\@tufte@caption@justification%
\noindent\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces#3\par%
```

see the file `tufte-common.def`.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces#3}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{graphic.pdf}
    \caption[Caption for the list of figures]{}
    \label{fig:figureX}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{graphic.pdf}
    \caption[Caption for the list of figures]{With caption}
    \label{fig:figureX}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

This is easily adapted to test whether the caption is empty or not, and to center the caption:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:
\ignorespaces#3}{\Centering
\csname fnum@#1\endcsname\ifblank{#3}{}{: \ignorespaces#3}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

[image: Centered sample]

Comment: That's what I was looking for. To center the figure label as well is as easy as \patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname: \ignorespaces#3}{\begin{center} \csname fnum@#1\endcsname\end{center}}{}{}

Comment: Very good - consistency with the other justification commands of this class would  actually suggest you use `\Centering` instead, see my updated answer.