# Print label in "figure" environment of tufte-book

Tags: floats, captions, tufte

This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148578/how-can-i-have-figure-labels-without-captions-in-tufte-book/148580#148580) explains how to get rid of captions for all figures in `tufte-book` class, but I need to remove captions just for figures which don't have caption. `marginfigure` environment has no problem with it and when the figure has no caption, it just prints its label (e.g. Figure 1:).

Now my question is how to do with `figure` environment (having figure with label). A sample code is like as the following:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{sine.pdf}
\caption{I have no text for this caption and need to only print the 
label.} %%% When I use \caption{}, I get nothing!
%\caption{}
\label{fig:figureX}
\end{center}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear what you mean exactly. Could you make a small example document (MWE) that illustrates the current and the desired behavior? A possible solution is not to use the `figure` environment at all (just put `\includegraphics` or `\begin{tikzpicture}` etc. directly at the preferred position in the document).

Comment: as a workaround you can use a single space (`\caption{ }`) which generates a label (but is not displayed itself).

Comment: @Marijn What a simple beautiful trick!