# Label-only behaviour for standard float with empty/blank caption when placed in margin

Tags: captions, tufte

How can I achieve the same label-only (no separator) behaviour for `\caption{}` when the label is to be placed on the margin?

I started from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148578/how-can-i-have-figure-labels-without-captions-in-tufte-book?noredirect=1&lq=1), but this does not apply for standard floats.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:
\ignorespaces#3}{
\csname fnum@#1\endcsname\ifblank{#3}{}{: \ignorespaces#3}}{}{}
\makeatother 


\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{graphic.pdf}
    \caption[Caption for the list of figures]{ }
    \label{fig:figureX}
  \end{center}
\end{figure}
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{4cm}
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{graphic.pdf}
    \caption[Caption for the list of figures]{}
    \label{fig:figureX}
  \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

"Figure 1:" (margin) vs. "Figure 2" (text column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to add a couple `\expandafter`s:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@caption}{\csname fnum@#1\endcsname:
\ignorespaces#3}{
\csname fnum@#1\endcsname\expandafter\ifblank\expandafter{#3}{}{: \ignorespaces#3}}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Since `#3` is `\@tufte@stored@caption` for regular figures/tables, `\ifblank` evaluates the else/false branch. Once `\@tufte@stored@caption` is expanded to a blank string by using `\expandafter`, `\ifblank` will work as expected.