# How to label a figure?

Tags: floats, captions

I understand how to put a caption on a figure, I'd do something like,

```
\begin{figure}[h]

...put figure here...

\label{figure1}\caption{this is a figure}

\end{figure}
```

and the caption reads,

```
Figure 1: this is a figure
```

which is all very well and good. However, I would dearly like my figure to only have the label,

```
Figure 1
```

without the caption. How would I do this?

(Basically, I have a figure that I want to reference, so I need it to have some label. It is perfectly fine without any caption, and adding one would detract from what is going on.)

Comment: Shouldn't `\caption[this is a figure]{}` do the trick?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Remove colon in the caption of a figure if the caption is empty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/remove-colon-in-the-caption-of-a-figure-if-the-caption-is-empty)

Comment: In addition to the (good) answers about getting an "empty" caption, please observe that `\label` **must** go **after** `\caption`, otherwise you won't get a correct reference to the figure number.

Comment: @StephanLehmke: I was wondering why the number was coming up wrong - I thought I had just accidentally merged some counters or something!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all: First the caption than the label.

It depends on your loaded documentclass and packages. For example you can simple write:

```
\caption[this is a figure]{}
```

And the output is:

> Figure 1:

The extra colon can be removed by changing the internal definition of the command `\@makecaption`. With no extra packages or a special class like memoir or KOMA you can use:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\mycaptsep{:\space}
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \ifx\ignorespaces#2\relax%
     \let\mycaptsep\relax%
  \fi%
  \sbox\@tempboxa{#1\mycaptsep #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    #1\mycaptsep #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]

...put figure here...
\caption{}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you are using the package caption it's more elegant. The package detects empty arguments of `\caption`:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]

...put figure here...
\caption{}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you are using a KOMA class you must change the separator. This can be done global:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper, 10pt]{scrartcl}
\renewcommand*{\captionformat}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]

...put figure here...
\caption{}
\label{figure1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you perhaps give a brief explanation of what the code in your first example is doing?

Comment: @user1729: I created a new command `\mycaptsep` to define a separator if the caption isn't empty. Then I redefined the internal command `\@makecaption` defined in the document class in this way that it uses the new command `\mycaptsep`.

Comment: Have you tested your redefined `\@makecaption` with some more examples, one with a non-empty caption?

IMHO the `\ifx\ignorespaces#2\relax` will always be true, because the standard `\caption` command in the LaTeX kernel expands this internal macro `\@makecaption` with a second argument starting with a `\ignorespaces` token (followed by the user caption text argument).  And if used with a non-empty caption you will get some additional text somewhere you don't want it.

Answer (score 7):

Try this.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[figurename=Figure]{caption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{4cm}{4cm}  
\caption{A nice figure}
\label{whatever}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

The [caption package](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) is loaded to get rid of any unwanted punctuation that could appear after the figure number.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe add a correctly positioned `\label`.

Comment: There's no need to use the `figurename=Figure` option; it's enough to load `caption`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina but it makes sense if one wants to set `figurename` to a value other than the default. I'm wondering if this can be done locally, can it?

Comment: @Erwann --- you can put something like `\captionsetup{name=goat}` inside a figure environment to cause a local change.