# Latex picture caption without text

Tags: captions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove colon in the caption of a figure if the caption is empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17725/remove-colon-in-the-caption-of-a-figure-if-the-caption-is-empty)

I want to add a picture with caption `Figure 1`, but without any additional text. I want the autonumbering.

If I do this

```
\begin{figure}[h!]
  \caption{}
  \includegraphics{graphics}
\end{figure}
```

I got `Figure 1:` in the result, which looks ugly.

I want just `Figure 1` in the text. I will explain elsewhere what the figure means. Can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `caption` does this automatically.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
  \centering
  \caption{Test}
\end{figure}
```

[image]